# Please explain the "apparent omission" of not including the women as the ones going into Cana'an after the 40-year wandering in the desert

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, women, eretz-yisrael, parashat-shelach, dor-hamidbar

I saw the explanation of how we know women entered Cana'an as listed in [the answer to this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/38650/did-women-and-levites-survive-the-40-years-in-the-wilderness). My question is regarding what seems to be an omission. The original complaint of the people in Bamidbar 14:3

> ...Our wives and our little ones will be a prey

But, in Bamidbar 14:31, when God explains the punishment, HE says:

> But your **little ones, that ye said would be a prey**, them will I bring in, and they shall know the land which ye have rejected.

The 2nd verse only mentions the little ones but not the women. Why did God omit explicitly mentioning the women in this verse, since he stated in verse 28:

> Say unto them: As I live, saith HaShem, **surely as ye have spoken in Mine ears**, so will I do to you:

Well, the people did specifically say that the women would also be a prey, but God does not specifically mention the women being rewarded.

Comment: As a logic question, perhaps some women did not last the 40 years because they lived out their natural life span. Thus, it could not be proven that the women were brought in to show that the complaint was improper. Since the entire next generation was brought into the land, then the response applying to them (men and women of the children's generation) was more forceful. Since I do not have a source and this is logic only, I am leaving it a comment.

Answer (score 1):

Good question. Maybe the women were omitted from vs 31 because the focus is on entering and 'knowing' the land, the women who will not own the land are perhaps not as a significant juxtaposition to the men who would have entered and owned but now will die. Whereas vs 3 was simply bemoaning the apparent eventual fate of all the week and helpless.

Comment: Except, as the story of Tzlofchad's daughters shows, women DO own land, sometimes.