# Why did no women speak up to support Yehoshua and Kalev's positive report about the land of Cana'an?

Tags: parashat-shelach, meraglim-spies

As a follow up to [this M.Y. question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/56377/from-where-do-we-learn-that-women-did-not-accept-the-report-of-the-meragelim/56381#56381) stating that women loved the land of Cana'an and very much desired to go there, why did no women support Kalev and Yehoshu'a's positive report? If it was a question of majority vs. minority, they would have outnumbered 10 spies.

**Premise**

Granted that all the spies physically visited the land and no women did, so one could argue that the people would believe testimony only from those who were actually there. However, both Kalev and Yehoshua based their positive claim on the faith and trust in G-d. The women would have supported that same claim, using the same strategy.

Comment: Who says they didnt?

Answer (score 1):

I shall give my answer here although it may be more appropriate to the question this is following up.
The question really should be why is it that the women wanted the land and not the men. This will also answer the question why the women couldnt speak up and influence the men. 
In a previous answer I wrote the 'yesod' that the reason why the benai yisroel in the desert made the golden calf and why they always wanted to go back to Egypt (whereas the women didnt want to make the golden calf and wanted to go to Israel, in Korah they didnt want to argue with moshe rabeinu so they saved their husband) is because the men learned torah which the women didnt. 
The torah in the desert was of the highest order. They were dor deiah. Everything they did was to make more torah. To stay in the desert would also have accomplished that. Korach was a bigger talmid chochom than Aaron (so says the sfas emes) so he deserved to be the kohen godol.

But that is not what hashem wants. If he did, he could carry on giving us manna in Israel. This has the disadvantage since one is not 'working', of falling for each ill wind like the yidden did in the desert. Torah has to be gained by working for it not by being given on a plate like in the desert. That is how hashem wants the world to be.  The women who always knew the truth would never have been able to explain it to the  men. Try telling someone today that Torah isnt everything and 'working' for it is more important.

Answer (score 1):

This comes from the Medrash on Parshas Pinchas, Parsha 21:10. The Medrash says that in that time the women fixed what the men ruined. They weren't part of the Egel and did not subscribe to the idea of the Meraglim.

Just like the Egel happened without the women getting in their way, this happened too. What we see is that they lived the land and looked forward to living there. This doesn't mean they actively negated anything that got in the way.

Answer (score 1):

According to some meforshim the meraglim first went among the families in order to panic the people about their children. As a result, when the men of the community started crying and complaining, the women too became afraid for their children and could no longer resist. As a result, the most they could do was keep quiet. The men were so panicked that they would not listen in any case.

Note that since the men were the soldiers, the women could not do anything. If they had managed to say anything, the demoralization of the men would have made the army incapable of fighting.

Thus, the women could not have stopped the men from refusing to fight. Similarly at cheit haegel, the women refused to give up their jewelry by could not stop the men from giving up their jewelry.